# Wordpress page menu with scrolling ability

Tags: html, css, wordpress, web, menu

Firstly i must say i am a complete novice in programming! That said, i need some help regarding an issue that seems for me impossible to solve.

What i need is a menu that on a single page remains fixed in the same position, (i'm not that sure but the idea is similar to a sticky menu that wouldn't be at the top) from which it's possible to scroll down to each page section with an anchorlink. I tried to use "scroll to page id" but sometimes it gets stuck, or doesn't even scroll down and worst of all, once the page scrolls the menu is gone. [image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZHXO.png).

I've been looking for days through plugins, stickymenus and other stuff but still haven't found the right solution. Any suggestions?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: What you need to do is make your letter a link to that section. In HTML you can link to not only other pages but also anything within a page. Take a look at this article. http://www.echoecho.com/htmllinks08.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can define your areas as sections instead of "page ids". After that is simple to navigate through those.

The Bootstrap Scrollspy is a nice way to do that simple: [Bootstrap Scrollspy example](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_scrollspy&stacked=h)